# How to filtered using value in array with nested json with JMESPath?

Tags: json, jmespath

I have this:

```
{
Item: [
        {
         key1: 'one',
         key2: 'two',
         key3: ["Sam", "Jack"]
        },
        {
         key1: 'one',
         key2: 'two',
         key3: ["Annie", "Jason"]
        }
     ]
}
```

So I wanted to get the object where its `key3` contains `"Annie"`.
The best expression I come up with `Items[].key3[?contain(@, 'Annie') == 'true']` which does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Well it looks to me like you are having multiple typos and then one big issue in you JMESPath expression.

First things first, for your JSON to be totally valid:

1. You should use double quotes, not single ones
2. Your names should be inclosed in double quotes too

<sup>*Source: https://restfulapi.net/json-syntax/*</sup>

So, here is your correct JSON data:

```json
{
  "Item": [
    {
      "key1": "one",
      "key2": "two",
      "key3": [
        "Sam",
        "Jack"
      ]
    },
    {
      "key1": "one",
      "key2": "two",
      "key3": [
        "Annie",
        "Jason"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Then, in your JMESPath you have two typos:

1. Your top level name is `Item` not `Items`
2. The correct JMESPath expression is `contains` and not `contain`

And finally, but maybe the most important issue your `contains` expression is incorrect, it tests the return of contains against the **string** `'true'` when [`contains` does return a boolean `true` or `false`](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#contains).

Because of this, you **have to** compare the return of `contains` against the [raw string literal](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#raw-string-literals) `` `true` ``.

So your correct query ends up being:

```
Item[].key3[?contains(@, `Annie`) == `true`]
```

Which gives:

```
[
  [],
  [
    "Annie"
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing commas (`,`) after `key1` and `key2`.

Using javascript:

```js
jsonObject= {
  Item: [
    {
      key1: 'one',
      key2: 'two',
      key3: ["Sam", "Jack"]
    },
    {
      key1: 'one',
      key2: 'two',
      key3: ["Annie", "Jason"]
    }
  ]
};

console.log(
  jsonObject.Item.filter(item=>item.key3.includes("Annie"))
);
```

Comment: Sorry, that's a typo. Thank you very much but could you provide an expression for JMESPath?

Comment: You are welcome!  Sorry, I cannot help you with JMESPath - I'm not familiar with it (yet...).